# JavaScript Using Regex to split string by capital letters except when together

Tags: javascript, match

I have a function:
     var header = key.match(/[A-Z][a-z]*/g);

This will take a string like TransactionID and make it into Transaction I D.

How do I make it split except where caps follow each other, in other words make this into

Transaction ID  or DOB into DOB instead of D O B?

I see the comments and have tried a few things, but the problem is this is a function that is fed a string of values to make a table header, and is used by several pages with different headers.

```
 function constructHeader(table, aligment, firstRow) {
    var thead = document.createElement('thead');
    table.appendChild(thead);
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var key in firstRow) {
       var header = key.match(/[A-Z][a-z]*/g);
       var newheader = '';
       for (var i = 0; i <= header.length; i++) {
         newheader += header[i] + ' ';
       }
    //  and so on
```

This takes the TransactionID and creates Transaction I D.  How do I change it so that it becomes Transaction ID?

Comment: 'transactionID'.match(/[a-z]+|[A-Z]+/g)

Comment: But what about the DOB string?

Comment: instead of 'transactionID'.match(/[a-z]+|[A-Z]+/g), use 
'DOB'.match(/[a-z]+|[A-Z]+/g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
key.match(/[a-z]+|[A-Z]+[a-z]*/g);
```

It will also work with "myFakeID"

EDIT: star was missing

Comment: This doesn't work, it takes DOB and still creates D O B

Comment: ?? In the console when I type 'DOB'.match(/[a-z]+|[A-Z]+[a-z]*/g);, I get ["DOB"]